# Shakespearian equivalent of 'very'

Tags: translation, shakespeare

What would the early modern english/shakespeare equivalent of 'very'be in the sentence:
'That was very nice'
?

Comment: I would worry much more about ***nice*** than about ***very*** in translating that sentence into Shakespearean English; ***nice*** has had a lot of meanings, and most of the ones in Shakespeare's time were fairly nasty: some of them (from the OED) are *foolish, silly, lascivious, showy, ostentatious, scrupulous, fastidious, refined, cowardly, effeminate, lazy, delicate, strange, shy, intricate, risky, trivial*.

Comment: It might have depended very much on what he was talking about. After all Shakespeare was not platitudinous. Nor would he have been politically correct. Had it been a beautiful young woman he may have said - for 'very nice' *No comelier creature was there in creation*. Which would have made any modern woman cringe!

Comment: If someone did a nice thing, how would it be phrased?

Comment: @LucyWilkinson What do you mean by 'nice'?

Comment: nice as in someone doing something friendly, or helpful

Answer (score 1):

The word "very" appears in Shakespeare's works frequently.

You can search for occurrences of specific words and phrases in Shakespeare's works using [Open Source Shakespeare](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/).

Comment: This answer currently functions more like a comment. Feel free to add information, transforming it into a good answer. Very = true or real like verily = truly or really. See http://www.william-shakespeare.info/william-shakespeare-dictionary-v.htm